# What is the best way to send a script with the initial index.html file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I am currently using this method in the index.html file; however, I want my javascript in a separate file, not inline.

```
<script> ... my code </script>
```

After some research, I see there are [server side includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-includes) which appear outdated but I'm not sure.

There are also [templating engines for express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html).

And thirdly, I imagine there is some way to concatenate the file using node libraries.

And fourthly, there are build tools such as webpack and grunt.  I am currently using webpack.

How can I parse all these options, and select the best one.

Answer (score 0):

The most conventional method people use is the 'src' attribute, which allows you to specify the URL of an external script file.
Syntax:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./path/to/your/script.js'/>
```